# Vikit_common - Installation failed - Raspberry Pi 2 B

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

I'm working an a project of drone and I'm having an issue with my Raspberry Pi 2 B. When I'm trying to install [vikit_common](https://github.com/uzh-rpg/rpg_svo/wiki/Installation:-Plain-CMake-(No-ROS)), I've this on screen :

> pi@raspberrypi ~/workspace/rpg_vikit/vikit_common/build $ cmake ..

```
-- Eigen found (include: /usr/include/eigen3)
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/pi/workspace/rpg_vikit/vikit_common/build
pi@raspberrypi ~/workspace/rpg_vikit/vikit_common/build $ make
[  7%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/vikit_common.dir/src/atan_camera.cpp.o
cc1plus: error: bad value (native) for -march switch
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mmmx’
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-msse’
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-msse’
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-msse2’
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-msse3’
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mssse3’
cc1plus: error: bad value (native) for -march switch
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mmmx’
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-msse’
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-msse’
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-msse2’
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-msse3’
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mssse3’
CMakeFiles/vikit_common.dir/build.make:57: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/vikit_common.dir/src/atan_camera.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/vikit_common.dir/src/atan_camera.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:168: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/vikit_common.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/vikit_common.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:116: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have Cmake installed (sudo apt-get cmake), Gcc (4.6.3) and OpenCV.

How can I solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you have an incorrect `cmake` configuration

A quick `gcc 4.6.3` man says

> -march=
>
> This specifies the name of the target ARM architecture. GCC uses this name to determine what kind of instructions it can use when
>   generating assembly code. This option can be used in conjunction with
>   or instead of the `-mcpu=' option. Permissable names are: **‘armv2’, ‘armv2a’, ‘armv3’, ‘armv3m’, ‘armv4’,‘armv4t’, ‘armv5’, ‘armv5t’, ‘armv5e’, ‘armv5te’, ‘armv6’, ‘armv6j’, ‘armv6t2’,‘armv6z’, ‘armv6zk’, ‘armv6-m’, ‘armv7’, ‘armv7-a’, ‘armv7-r’, ‘armv7-m’,‘iwmmxt’, ‘iwmmxt2’, ‘ep9312’**

Firstly looks like you have a wrong value for `-march`.

So check your `cmake` configuration